# Modeling chemical reactions: can Mathematica tell the end result of a reaction?

Tags: chemistry

I am curious about using Mathematica for modelling chemical reactions but don't really know much about the Mathematica software yet.

So I was reading [this page](http://www.wolfram.com/solutions/industry/chemistry/) at wolfram.com which explains some of the capabilities of Mathematica. The page explains that:

> Mathematica includes thousands of built-in functions and curated data on many topics that let you:
>
> - Access physical and safety properties of chemicals in your laboratory
>     using built-in chemical data
> - Calculate path-dependent and path-independent quantities such as
>     entropy, free energy, chemical potential, and more
> - Simulate mass transport and chemical kinetics such as electrochemical
>     reactions
> - Calculate the time-independent Schrödinger equation and its solutions
>     in terms of wave functions and their eigenvalues, and other
>     applications in quantum chemistry
> - Solve coupled nonlinear differential equations for chemical kinetics
>     modeling Interactively visualize molecular structures of biochemical
>     compounds

So considering that chemical reactions can have a lot of variations (depending on ambient and solution temperatures, and other factors), I wanted to ask a couple of questions:

1. Does this mean that Mathematica can calculate the results of formulas (such as this relatively simple one: Na+ + OH-  + H+ + Cl-)?
2. What are the limitations in calculating chemical reactions (does it only provide approximate solutions, only known formulas, or only for specific air pressure and temperature, etc)?

Comment: Not as straightforward as it is made to sound. You still have to set up all the equations yourself.

Comment: Actually the answer to this question at Quora seems to imply that it's not possible: https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Mathematica-create-a-chemical-calculator-were-you-can-see-the-results-of-chemical-reactions. Although Wolfram does provide some examples, like this one: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/ChemicalReactions.html so maybe that Quora answer is just incorrect.

Comment: It isn't impossible to do it, but to get reliable results in the general case you would need to do some fairly high-level quantum chemical calculations, of the sort that would probably require a compute cluster to finish in a reasonable time. *Mathematica* isn't really suited to this application. I think you're better off to take the so-called capabilities as suggestions for what you *could* do, if you really wanted to. It doesn't mean *Mathematica* will make it easy for you, much less do it without any effort on your part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not aware of all chemistry capabilities of Mathematica, but I hope this answer provides couple of starting points.

### The first question

> I am curious about using Mathematica for modelling chemical reactions
>   but don't really know much about it yet.

Which area is not known much? Mathematica or modeling of chemical reactions?

If we assume the former see [Wolfram Demonstration project search results for "chemistry reactions modeling"](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=chemistry%20reactions%20modeling).

Also, see the documentation page ["Chemical Reactions"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/ChemicalReactions.html).

### Reactions

There is a **Chemical equations balancer** available through WolframAlpha. See for example:

**1.** [W|A: "Na+ + OH- + H+ + Cl- -> H2O + NaCl"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Na%2B+%2B+OH-+%2B+H%2B+%2B+Cl-+-%3E+H2O+%2B+NaCl)

```
WolframAlpha["Na+ + OH- + H+ + Cl- -> H2O + NaCl"]
```

**2.** [W|A : "KMnO4 + HCl -> KCl + MnCl2 + H2O + Cl2"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=KMnO4+%2B+HCl+-%3E+KCl+%2B+MnCl2+%2B+H2O+%2B+Cl2)

```
WolframAlpha["KMnO4 + HCl -> KCl + MnCl2 + H2O + Cl2"]
```

I wrote the first version of the balancer 9 years ago, and I know that it handles multiple possible reaction outcomes, but I do not think that the multiple reaction outcomes feature is exposed to the users.

Data of the elements relevant for making reactions can be accessed with `EntityValue`. E.g.:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @AntonAntonov, I clarified my question with what I intended to say earlier (what I meant to say was that I do not know much about Mathematica, although my knowledge of chemical reactions in general is not that great either at the moment - it is something that I am studying). Sounds pretty cool that you wrote the Chemical equations balancer used by Wolfram. But are you saying that it may not be exposed (available) through the Mathematica interface (GUI)?

Comment: @user100487 The Chemical Equation Balancer (CEB) is available at/through W|A -- try the command `WolframAlpha["KMnO4 + HCl -> KCl + MnCl2 + H2O + Cl2"]`.  But not all features of CEB are surfaced to the end users.

Comment: Thanks @AntonAntonov, I tried that command in the Mathematica 10.1 I have on my PC and after a few seconds the information shown in this screen shot appeared: http://i.stack.imgur.com/knZqz.png